# Excel append all rows with data into master-sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know VB so I searched and copied this macro to accomplish my need to append all rows with data from sheets in the same workbook starting from row 10 into a master-sheet.
I need to modify the macro so that the data will be appended into the master sheet starting from row 10 because in rows 1-9 there are the headings.

```
Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim shLast As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'Fill in the start row
    StartRow = 10

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Loop through all worksheets except the RDBMerge worksheet and the
        'Information worksheet, you can ad more sheets to the array if you want.
        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, _
                                     Array(DestSh.Name, "Information"), 0)) Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh and sh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
            shLast = LastRow(sh)

            'If sh is not empty and if the last row >= StartRow copy the CopyRng
            If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then

                'Set the range that you want to copy
                Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

                'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
                If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                End If

                'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
                'values or want to copy everything look below example 1 on this page
                CopyRng.Copy
                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

            End If

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.GoTo DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Could someone please give me indications on what to change to start pasting from row 10?

Comment: What does the code for 'LastRow' look like?  If I had to guess, I would say it should look for the first empty row.  Depending what's in there, you can force this line to be 10 at the start if needed: 'Last = LastRow(DestSh)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your code determines the last row in `DestSh` from a custom function called `LastRow`. Therefore it would seem like you need to change something in that function in order to avoid override of your initial 10 first rows.

Although we do not know what your data exactly looks like, I would expect that you could avoid using the `LastRow` function and instead replase the line `With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")`
 with this line:

```
With DestSh.Cells(DestSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A")
```

This will find the last empty row of column `A` in `DestSh` and paste the copied range there.